# How to use an Angular app as your View Engine with Node.js

Tags: node.js, angular

I am trying to create an Angular app that sends an email using Nodemailer.

I am able to create a standard Angular app that contains a form. I then want to pass data from this form to a .JS file which will then use Nodemailer to send that data to an email address.

All the examples I have found so far for Nodemailer use View engines such as handlebars, etc. but I want to use my angular app's HTML rather than a view engine.

How do I pass data from my Angular app's form to a .JS file to send an email without having to use a View Engine?

Below is what I have so far in my Angular app:

```
<form method="POST" action="send">
      <p>
          <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="name">
      </p>
      <p>
          <label>Company</label>
          <input type="text" name="company">
      </p>
      <p>
          <label>Email Address</label>
          <input type="email" name="email">
      </p>
      <p>
          <label>Phone Number</label>
          <input type="text" name="phone">
      </p>
      <p class="full">
          <label>Message</label>
          <textarea name="message" rows="5"></textarea>
      </p>
      <p class="full">
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </p>
  </form>
```

And this is what I have in the tutorial code:

APP.JS

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
const path = require("path");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const app = express();

// View engine setup
app.engine("handlebars", exphbs());
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");

// Static folder
app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("contact");
});

app.post("/send", async (req, res) => {
  const output = `
    <p>You have a new contact request</p>
    <h3>Contact Details</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
        <li>Company: ${req.body.company}</li>
        <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
        <li>Phone: ${req.body.phone}</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Message</h3>
    <p>${req.body.message}</p>    
    `;

    try{
        var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({      
            service: "gmail",
            auth: {
              user: "myemail@mail.com",
              pass: "myPassword"
            },
            tls: {
              rejectUnauthorized: false
            }
          });
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err.message);
    }

  const mailOptions = {
    from: "myemail@mail.com", // sender address
    to: "myemail@mail.com", // list of receivers
    subject: "Test email", // Subject line
    html: output // plain text body
  };

  let info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);

  console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
  console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

  res.render("contact", { msg: "Email has been sent" });
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server started..."));
```

CONTACT.HANDLEBARS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Acme Web Design</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="brand"><span>Acme</span> Web Design</h1>
        <div class="wrapper animated bounceInLeft">
            <div class="company-info">
                <h3>Acme Web Design</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-road"></i> 44 Something st</li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> (555) 555-5555</li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> test@acme.test</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="contact">
                <h3>Email Us</h3>
                {{ msg }}
                <form method="POST" action="send">
                    <p>
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label>Company</label>
                        <input type="text" name="company">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label>Email Address</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label>Phone Number</label>
                        <input type="text" name="phone">
                    </p>
                    <p class="full">
                        <label>Message</label>
                        <textarea name="message" rows="5"></textarea>
                    </p>
                    <p class="full">
                        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </p>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I can post further code if necessary.

Comment: I would create node API that takes data and sends it for you.
You can than run both ng serve and node on different ports and make angular to call that node api. You will need to set up cors on server side to do that.  Here is some basic example https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-backend-express/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to pass data from the form *(root.component.html)* to the server *(app.js)*, capture it & print it to the console via the POST method.

Code is below:

**root.component.html:**

```
<form #emailForm="ngForm">
    <div class="col-md-6">            
          <div>
            <label for="username">
              Username
            </label>
            <input              
              type="text"
              id="username"
              [(ngModel)]="username"
              required
              name="username"
              #txtUsername="ngModel"
            />            
          </div>
          <div>
            <label for="message">Message</label>
            <textarea 
             id="message"
              placeholder="Please enter your message here"
              [(ngModel)]="message"
              required
              name="message"
              #txtMessage="ngModel"
            ></textarea>
          </div>               
          <button
            axis-button
            class="axis-btn"
            title="Submit"
            data-kind="primary"
            (click)="sendMessage()"
            [disabled]="emailForm.invalid"
          >
            Send Email
          </button>        
    </div>
</form>
```

**root.component.ts:**

```
export class RootComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private rootService: RootService) {}

  username: string;
  message: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();

  }

  getData() {
    this.rootService.getAPIData().subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log('response from GET API is ', response);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('error is ', error);
      }
    );
  }

  postData(name: string, message: string) {
    this.rootService.postAPIData(name, message).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log('response from POST API is ', response);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('error during post is ', error);
      }
    );
  }

  sendMessage() {
    this.postData(this.username, this.message);
  }
}
```

**root.service.ts:**

```
export class RootService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getAPIData() {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
  }

  postAPIData(name: string, message: string) {
    return this.http.post('/api/postData', {
      name: name,
      message: message
    });
  }
}
```

**app.js:**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')   

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Welcome to Node API')
})

app.get('/getData', (req, res) => {
    res.json({'message': 'Hello World'})
})

app.post('/postData', bodyParser.json(), (req, res) => {
    res.json(req.body) // Prints the request body to the browser console   
    const output = `Name: ${req.body.name}......Email: ${req.body.message}`;
    console.log(output);
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```